# Как в postman задать вместо ip макрос

Tags: postman, макрос

Есть POST URL по которому находится мой контроллер http://localhost:8088/api/v1/source/addSourceAndType

Задача - вместо http://localhost:8088/ использовать макрос {ip}

Я создал переменную
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но такая конструкция не сработала
{ip}api/v1/source/addSourceAndType

Comment: [Ну Вы, блин, даёте!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kx01Aj39wg). В столбце `Variable` введите `baseUrl`, в столбец `CurrentValue` введите `http://localhost:8098/api/v1`. В таком случае следующий паттерн должен сработать: `{{baseUrl}}/source/addSourceAndType`.